# Fuse File System Indicate Files Should NOT be Opened

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse

I'm implementing a fuse file system for a remote Internet server.  When I open my mountpoint in a file browser (like Caja or Nautilus), the file browser tries to generate thumbnails of the files.  In order to do so, it needs to read the files.  Since the files aren't local, this turns out to be a very expensive operation.

I'd like to indicate to the file browsers that they should not attempt to generate thumbnails for these files.  Presumably there is some flag I can set, but I'm at a loss for which keywords to search / how to describe what I'm looking for.

To be clear: I'm not trying to disable thumbnails just on my machine/configuration, I'm looking for a (relatively general) way of communicating to a generic file browser that the FS is remote and it should avoid generating thumbnails.

Anyone know how a FUSE FS can tell the file browser to not do the reads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is an unsolvable problem for any filesystem. If you can indicate to the OS that the filesystem is of network type (on Windows this can be done), chances are that the file browser respects the FS type and reduces the number of read operations.